# Что значит void function?

Tags: javascript

Я знаю что значит void 0 (void условие), но не понимаю что значит void function. Что это значит и зачем это? Как это может использоваться с анонимными и обычными функциями? И я часто встречал примерно вот такие записи:

```js
void function foo(){...}
void function(){...}
void function foo(){...}()
void function(){...}()
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/468229/

Answer (score 0):

> Что это значит и зачем это?

**Для рекурсивных функций, чтобы они помнили название самих себя, но не существовали.**

```
var calls={max:4,now:0};
void function myFunc() {
    ++calls.now;
    if (calls.now===calls.max) {
        console.log(calls.now);
    } else {
        myFunc();
    }
}()
console.log(typeof myFunc)
```

Собственно, в этом нет смысла, если оборачивать анонимную функцию в `;(function(){})(/*здесь вызов*/);`, но там это делается дольше, как в последней иллюстрации;

Аналоги(?), подробнее:

```
//напишите 'use strict' и уберите ';' для ошибки
//явно нужно указать var=(эта функция)() для получения обработки;
;(()=>{
    //стрелочные функции плохая практика (здесь)
    //т.к. в случае сниппетов урезан arguments
    return null;
})(); //по той же причине, что и 'use strict' здесь ';'
```

Нагляднее:

```
;(function(){
    for (var insecVarIfSnippetWhenConstUsing of Array.from(arguments)) {
        if (typeof insecVarIfSnippetWhenConstUsing!='number') throw(`only numbers`);
    }
    return {then(x){console.log(x)}};
})(2,'эта строка спровоцирует ошибку').then('Hello, World!');
```

Пример для, видимо, генеративного программирования.

Однако возникает вопрос касательно рекурсии (мы же "типа защищаем" переменные):

```
//намеренно вычурный пример
;(function(noConstForRecursive){
    doRecursive=Object.assign(true, {max:4, arr:[]});
    function noConstForRecursive(arg){
        if (arguments.length!=0) {
            doRecursive.arr.push(arg);
        }
        doRecursive=Object.assign((doRecursive.max>doRecursive.arr.length), doRecursive);
        if (doRecursive==true) { //наглядный пример == против ===, к слову
            noConstForRecursive(Math.random());
        }
        if (arguments.length==0) return doRecursive.arr;
    }
    
    console.log(noConstForRecursive())
})();
```

Чтобы рекурсии делать красивее и нужен `void` в начале функции (чтобы не висело в памяти; собственно, отсюда мои предъявления `const`-пользователям становятся понятнее - `<script></script>` без блока внутри, объявивший `const` и вот +ещё одна проблема в коде).

**? зачем**: к примеру, инсталятор `rust`, а также прочие, его, файлы от своего названия меняют поведение. (популярный пример); если Ваши программы совместимы или имеет своё поведение для браузера, NodeJS (`.load`, `eval()`, `mainModule` (`sig?`), `require()!=mainModule`) и т.д., при том, безопасны (включительно, от `const`-пользователей (и без `fork` и `scriptTag`)), то, вероятно, это сниппеты такого типа:

Иллюстрации концепта, где скрипт узнаёт свою элевацию, модификацию (или Ctrl+C/V):

https://codeberg.org/slnknrr/js.nodejs21.snippets/src/branch/main/ssfindex224.js

(это сниппет и он в ленивой разработке)

Comment: Итог: можно комбинировать `void` и обрётку анонимной функции для защиты переменных через `(arguments)`. //максимально читабельно и безопасно в нынешних реалиях любителей `const`

Comment: Больше адекватности примеров с рекурсиями через `void` - `this.моя_переменная`, но это первый объект с `моя_переменная` из `arguments` (неисключительно, `(arguments)`).